# Non trivial extensions of the zero map

Tags: modules, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

Suppose we have short exact sequences of $R$-modules $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$ and $0 \to A' \to B' \to C' \to 0$ with a map of short exact sequences $f_A : A \to A', f_B : B \to B', f_C : C \to C'$.

If $f_A =0, f_C = 0$, is it true that $f_B = 0$? What if both short exact sequences are split?

Comment: If both sequences are split, the uniqueness of the middle map should follow from the universal property of biproduct, no?

Comment: Sorry, i have just discovered the answer a few minutes later... it turns out to be false!! It's surprising to me.

Comment: Yes, bit surprising indeed. Wouldn't surprise me in general, but in the split case it does.

Answer (score 2):

It's false. Suppose $A=C$ and $B= A \oplus A$. The map $f_B = A \oplus A \to A \oplus A$ given by $(a,b) \mapsto (b,0)$ is zero when restricted to the first component, and is zero if we quotient out the first component, but it's not zero globally.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's not clear to me what saying "$f_A : A \to A'$ is a short exact sequence" means (it's been a long time since I did this stuff). I think that any sequence of two R-modules is "exact" because at each module, you have only one map. Did you perhaps mean that $0 \to A \to A' \to 0$ is short exact? If so, then $f_A$ is an isomorphism.
2. As written, if I'm following what you've asked...

Consider

```
0 -> Z  -> Z -> Z/2Z -> 0
     |     |      |
     V     V      V
0 -> Z  -> Z -> Z/2Z -> 0
```

where the first horizontal map in each row is $x \to 2x$, and the first and third vertical maps are zero, but the middle map is the identity.

This has all the properties you specified, but the middle vertical map isn't zero.

I believe you wanted to add the assumption that the diagram consisting of all your maps is actually *commutative*. Even with that assumption, I'm not sure of whether the statement is true (although I suspect it might be).

Comment: "with a map of short exact sequences" assumes that the diagram is commutative.

Comment: Hi John! I have two short exact sequences, and the triple $(f_A, f_B, f_C)$ is a map of short exact sequences. In other words, the diagram made up of the two short exact sequences plus the maps $(f_A, f_B, f_C)$ is required to be commutative.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up my misunderstanding, folks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "no" even if both are split, but this is not strange if you are used to nilpotent maps: suppose that $R=\mathbb R$ say, and consider the short exact sequence

$$
0 \to \mathbb R \to^i \mathbb R^2 \to^q \mathbb R \to 0 
$$
where the first map is given by $i(t)=te_1$ and the second map is given by $q(ae_1+be_2)=b$.

This short exact sequence essentially just filters $\mathbb R^2$ by the line $L=\mathbb R.e_1$, so that a map $\alpha\colon \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ induces an endomorphism of the short exact sequence provided it preserves $L$ *i.e.* its matrix $A$ with respect to the standard basis is upper triangular, so $A = \left(\begin{array}{cc}a  & b \\ 0 & c \end{array}\right) = aE_{11}+bE_{12} +cE_{22}$ -- indeed that is exactly what is required in order for $\alpha$ to induce maps between the two outer terms in the short exact sequence. Those maps on the outer terms, however, are given by the diagonal terms $aE_{11}$ and $cE_{22}$ respectively, and so requiring that they are zero places no restriction on $bE_{12}\in \text{Hom}(\mathbb R^2,i(\mathbb R))$.